# MySQL maximum value longtext

Tags: mysql, max

This is my table structure:

```
Table: tablex

ID | article_value     
 1    11500
 2    12
```

`article_value` is of datatype `longtext`, which I can't change due to circumstances.

I try to retrieve the highest value of `article_value` with this:

```
SELECT CAST( MAX( tablex.article_value ) AS UNSIGNED ) highestcomment
    FROM tablex
```

But this ain't working since it outputs 12 instead of 11500.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You are doing it in the wrong order.

```
SELECT MAX( CAST(tablex.article_value AS UNSIGNED )) highestcomment FROM tablex
```

If you are first finding the maximum, you haven't casted to integer yet, so the values will be compared as strings: `12` > `11500`.

I also suggest you think about the circumstances again. Converting the column to an integer type would remove the need to cast the values and will make this query faster.

Comment: The exact result that I was looking for 